# My data posts to a new page rather than the specified div

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why does my post data appear on a new blank page rather than the div I specified? This script is in the head of a page called order.php. I want the data submitted to be written in the "message" div I created on order.php. But when I submit, I am redirected to update.php where the data is written on a blank page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insert() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XLMHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        parameters = 'child_name'+document.getElementById('child_name').value;

        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'update.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(parameters); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Because you told it to: `xmlhttp.open('POST', 'update.php', true);`

Comment: @Andy so what is the problem with that...??

Answer (score 0):

you current page is `order.php` and your posting it to `update.php` by doing this `xmlhttp.open('POST', 'update.php', true);`

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to normal form submission event.

```
use a simple jquery

$("#form").submit(function(){
 $.post("update.php",{paramertes:'child_name_'+$("#child_name").val()},function(data){
$("#message").html(data);
})

 return false;//don't forget to use this
})
```